# don't see the call button enabled in Virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am new to android development and installed the ADT. I have Created AVD and launched the emulator. But the problem is that I don't see the call button enabled. Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Some AVD device definitions disallow the AVD from displaying "hardware controls".  You can change the settings for this in the Eclipse AVD manager, if that's what you're using, or you can alter the AVD class settings for the device by hacking the files that tell the IDE what (let's just say a Nexus 7) the physical device is like.  A Nexus 7 has an all-glass screen, so no "virtual button" will show up on emulator, but if you emulate an older android flip phone with a physical keypad, the AVD emulator will show those as "virtual buttons".

You can go hack the device definition files by hand in a text editor to allow virtual "hardware buttons" to show up in the emulator (look for something like "hardwarekeys=true",
or you can chose another device to emulate that actually came with physical buttons, since that AVD definition will already be set to display some virtual "buttons".